# String of numbers to a list of integers?

Tags: python

I've been presented with the task of turning a string of mixed numbers ("1 3 5 8 10"), for example, and my goal is to put these numbers into a list as integers.

I have the knowledge and know-how to split the string and int() them to turn them in to integers, but the issue comes in *how* I'm doing it.
The specific issue I'm having is when it comes to looping through the string, finding the chars, and turning them into ints.
As it's looping through and gets to 10 (or any 2 digit number), it turns each number into its own digit; so: 10 would be [1, 0], not [10].

Please excuse the mess of code here, I've been trying to see what's going on each step with prints:

```
def iq_test(numbers):
    print(numbers)
    nums = []
    numbers.split(" ")
    nums.append(numbers)
    print (numbers)
    for char in numbers:
        if char == " ":
            del char
        else:
            nums.append(int(char))  # Problem arises here, where a 2 digit number is being added to the list as 2 separate numbers
    print(nums)
```

Still very new to coding, so if you notice a major logic problem I'm running into, I'd appreciate it if you pointed it out to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `numbers.split(" ")` on its own isn't doing anything useful. Assign it to a variable. Also, if you give no parameters, it will always split on spaces, so you can use that.

```
nums = numbers.split()
```

With that, you should use `for num in nums` to loops over the split elements rather than looping over *characters* of the input string.

In any case, you can shorten all of this by using  a list-comprehension to apply that int function and return the list of integers.

And you've defined a function, so you should `return` the value, not only print it.

```
nums = [int(s) for s in numbers.split()] 
return nums
```

And then you would `print(iq_test("1 2 3 10"))`

Comment: This seems to be the exact solution I needed. Thanks for detailing where I was going wrong, too. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
s = "1 3 5 8 10"
final_data = list(map(int, re.findall('\d+', s)))
print(final_data)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def iq_test(numbers):
    nums = []
    for num in numbers.split():
        nums.append(int(num))
```

I guess ... you could(and probably should) just do a list comprehension instead

```
 nums = [int(num) for num in numbers.split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong array for iteration and also doing some wrong conversions:

```
def iq_test(numbers):
    print(numbers)
    nums = []
    for number in numbers.split(" "):
         nums.append(int(number))
    print(nums)
```